# "Process exited with error(s)" but no errors are reported

Tags: errors, miktex, miktex2.9, compilation-error

I'm using Miktex 2.9 and TexStudio. I cannot compile anything, including this simple document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

The only error reported is "Process exited with error(s)". The log file contains this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.8.10)  28 MAR 2018 16:19
entering extended mode
**./texstudio_YJ9064.tex
(texstudio_YJ9064.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 1
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(texstudio_YJ9064.aux)
\openout1 = `texstudio_YJ9064.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
 [1

{C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file C:/Users/David Scott/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9
/pdftex/config/pdftex.map): buffer overflow at file C:\Jenkins\jobs\miktex-2.9\
workspace\source\Programs\TeXAndFriends\pdftex\source\mapfile.c, line 418
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

To my knowledge, I did not change anything with my installation between when LaTeX worked and when it stopped.

Comment: `buffer overflow`. Well that's new. It looks as if your map-file is corrupted. Try to recreate it by calling `updmap` on a command line, or by using the task "recreate font map files" in the miktex console (as user).

Comment: Setting updmap as a user-defined tool in TexStudio worked! (Options->Configure->Build) Thanks a bunch! Do you want to post this as an actual answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I added an answer. Could you also add the miktex tag to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file C:/Users/David Scott/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9
/pdftex/config/pdftex.map): buffer overflow at file C:\Jenkins\jobs\miktex-2.9\
workspace\source\Programs\TeXAndFriends\pdftex\source\mapfile.c, line 418
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

This sounds as if `pdftex.map` is corrupted. You should recreate it and check if this resolves the problem.

As your map is in your user profile this can be done by calling either on a command line

`updmap`

or by using in the miktex console (started as user) the task `recreate font map files`.